# How to get login logs using Flask/MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, flask, mysql-python

I would like to display the login logs (who connected and when) after the login screen, on the home page for example (so the user sees when he logged in last time) and store the data in a file if possible (that way we see who logged in and when).

I have a simple authentification with Flask/MySQL :

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def login():

    # Open database connection
    db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","#{elma3alem}","FilesList")

    # prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
    cursor = db.cursor()

    # execute SQL query using execute() method.
    cursor.execute("SELECT userName, password FROM User")

    # Fetch a single row using fetchone() method.
    data = cursor.fetchall()
    error = None

    if request.method == 'POST':
        for row in data:
            if request.form['username'] != row[0] or request.form['password'] != row[1]:
                error = 'Invalid Credentials. Please try again.'
            else:
                return render_template('files_list.html')

    return render_template('login.html', error=error)

    # disconnect from server
    db.close()
```

And this is my `login` page :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/style.css" type="text/css">
{% block body %}
{% if session['logged_in'] %}
<p>You're logged in already!</p>
{% else %}


<form action="/login" method="POST" name="login">
    <div class="login">
        <div class="login-screen">
            <div class="app-title">
                <h1>Login</h1>
            </div>

            <div class="login-form">
                <div class="control-group">
                <input type="text" class="login-field" value="" placeholder="username" name="username">
                <label class="login-field-icon fui-user" for="login-name"></label>
                </div>

                <div class="control-group">
                <input type="password" class="login-field" value="" placeholder="password" name="password">
                <label class="login-field-icon fui-lock" for="login-pass"></label>
                </div>

                <input type="submit" value="Log in" class="btn btn-primary btn-large btn-block" >
                <br>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

I guess I need to use stuff like `login manager`,`login_required` etc...but I don't know how to start.

Thanks beforehand.